# Download .tar.gz 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, tar

I know there's a lot of questions about downloading .tar.gz files, but I haven't found any that explain my problem. When I'm trying to install these files, using the

```
./configure
make
sudo make install.
```

But when I use `./config`, it returns `bash: ./config: No such file or directory`. Same with `make` and `sudo make install`. Am I doing wrong, or is there just an error with my computer?
As I said, this is not the same question as "how to download .tar.gz files" because I tried their solution and it didn't work. There is no ./configure file to cd into.

Comment: I'm assuming you cd'd into the correct directory.  If you do an `ls`, do you see a file called `config`?

Comment: Did you `cd` to the directory?

Comment: The first thing you're doing wrong is *assuming all tar archives contain source code that is buildable using the `./configure - make - make install` paradigm*: they may contain code for other build systems such as `cmake` or `scons`, or may not even contain source code at all. The second error is using `./config` - the script (if it exists) will almost certainly be called `./configure`

Comment: There's a folder called configuration, but there isn't much that looks usable. The contents of configuration are  config.ini org.eclipse.equinox.source org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator org.eclipse.update

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're doing it wrong. First of all, `tar.gz` is simply a compressed archive. Think of it as a zip file. There is no guarantee that it will have a configuration script. That said, the default name for the configuration script is `configure`, not `config`.

So, the standard operating procedure to install from a source tarball is:

```
tar xvzf foo.tzr.gz
cd foo
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: same resulte with `./configure` I'm trying to install Eclipse and a JRE, if that helps at all.

Comment: @James everything depends on the contents of whatever you downloaded. If it's a JRE, I very much doubt that any configure script is available. Where did you download this from? There should be instructions there. I can't help unless you edit your question and tell us what you downloaded, where from, how you extracted it and the contents of the folder you extracted it into. More importantly, what's wrong with `sudo apt-get install eclipse`?

Comment: Never tried that one. I couldn't find a .deb version of eclipse so I assumed I couldn't get it through `apt-get install`. I downloaded the JRE from Java.

Comment: @James http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/eclipse it should be easy enough to install. If that is what you end up doing, please delete your question since it won't help anyone else. If you still want to install from source, follow the instructions on their website. I'm sure they explain.

Comment: @James if you are trying to install Eclipse probably you only have to exctract the contents of the .tar.gz file and move them to any location you want. Take a look on [how to install eclipse](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/) from source

Comment: @terdon your link doesn't have any discernible download. I'm using @migrc link to try and install directly from source, but so far no dice. I tried `sudo apt-get install eclipse` and it didn't work. `E: package not found`.

Comment: Meh. I got wine to work correctly so I'll just run an exe through wine. It's working just fine.

Comment: @James there is a installer for linux in the eclipse project webpage. [Try it](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux) (there are 32 and 64 bits versions)